# How to add an onclick event handler after a specific action happens?

Tags: javascript, html, css, button

I want to enable the second button to be clicked only after the first button has been clicked. The button that I want to enable is the start variable in JS. This is how I did it:

```
<!--One of these "buttons" has to be clicked to enable clicking of another one-->
<li id="easy" class="list" onclick="shadows(1)">Easy</li>
<li id="medium" class="list" onclick="shadows(2)">Medium</li>
<li id="hard" class="list" onclick="shadows(3)">Hard</li>
<!--it goes to another function shadows()-->
```

Here is the function:

```
function shadows(number){
 start.style.cursor="pointer";
 shadow=1;//I set a variable to 1(It was previously 0)

 start.style.backgroundColor="#ffffb3";
 start.onmouseenter=function(){
  start.style.backgroundColor="yellow";
 };
  start.onmouseleave=function(){
  start.style.backgroundColor="#ffffb3";
 };

}
```

I later check if shadow variable is 1

```
if(shadow==1){
start.onclick=function(){
 easy.style.display="none";
 medium.style.display="none";
 hard.style.display="none";
 randomExercise();
 };
}
```

I attempt to add onclick event, but it doesn't work. Nothing happens when the button is clicked. How can I fix this?

Comment: So you wish for medium to be accessible only after easy has been clicked and so on?

Comment: @Erik Seems like I already got an answer. I wanted the "start" button to appear after any items of the list were clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your shadows function you can add the event listener like so:

```
 function shadows(number){
 start.style.cursor="pointer";

 start.style.backgroundColor="#ffffb3";
 start.onmouseenter=function(){
  start.style.backgroundColor="yellow";
 };
  start.onmouseleave=function(){
  start.style.backgroundColor="#ffffb3";
 };

 start.addEventListener("click", function(){
     easy.style.display="none";
     medium.style.display="none";
     hard.style.display="none";
     randomExercise(); 
 });
}
```

The reason it didn't work how you had it before is because your original script only runs once when you load the page, at which time shadow was 0.  That is part of the reason why event handlers are so handy.